# Problems running local GAE application: Unresolved compilation problems

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I moved my project directory to another computer, then I had this problem:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /index.jsp. Reason:

    java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method find(Class, long) in the type Objectify is not applicable for the arguments (Class, Long)
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Usuario
    The method delete(Class, long) in the type Objectify is not applicable for the arguments (Class, Long)
    Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5
    Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5
    Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5
    Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5
```

- My Objectify JAR is already set in the build path
- As my JRE Library, I'm using JDK 1.7.0_02
- As my APP ENGINE SDK, I'm using 1.6.1.1

I have already followed a lot of guides to solve similar problems, like uninstall and reinstall all my JRE/JDK, and nothing worked. I don't know what to do anymore. Hope somebody can help me with that issue, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention your JRE but Eclipse also has "Compiler compliance level". Is it possible that it was set to 1.4 or something?

Another possibility is that your project is using a non-standard JRE even though 1.7 is the default.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all: you're trying to invoke the find method with an instance of the Long-class, while the method expects a long. It seems that the java used by the GAE doesn't provide auto-boxing so you have to perform the boxing yourself by using the longValue() of the java.lang.Long class.

Comment: that's not the problem, for sure. The same exactly project was running ok in other computer.